# Can I create a matrix ODE of lagrangian equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics

This is the first time I doing a system of lagrangian equations
Here is a robotic arm which are put in a spinning disc with the mass $m_3$ and diameter $L_3$. The $T_1  , T_2, T_3$ are just momentum forces. Never mind of those here.

[image]

I wonder if I can create system of lagrangian equations like this:

$${\mathcal{L}} = [KE] - [PE]$$

$${\mathcal{L}}_1 = [\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + J_1\ddot{\theta_1}] - [m_1gh_1]$$
$${\mathcal{L}}_2 = [\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 + J_2\ddot{\theta_2}] - [m_2g(h_1 + h_2)]$$
$${\mathcal{L}}_3 = [J_3\ddot{\theta_3}] - [0]$$

Where:

Intertia:
$$J_1 = m_1L_1^2$$
$$J_2 = m_2L_2^2$$
$$J_3 = m_1L_1^2cos(\theta_1) + m_2[L_1^2cos(\theta_1) + L_1^2cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)] + m_3\frac{L_3^2}{2^2}$$

Velocity:

$$v_1^2 = \dot{x_1}^2 + \dot{y_1}^2$$
$$\dot{x_1} = L_1cos(\theta_1)\dot{\theta_1}$$
$$\dot{y_1} = -L_1sin(\theta_1)\dot{\theta_1}$$
$$v_2^2 = \dot{x_2}^2 + \dot{y_2}^2$$
$$\dot{x_2} = L_2cos(\theta_2)\dot{\theta_2}$$
$$\dot{y_2} = -L_2sin(\theta_2)\dot{\theta_2}$$

Height:

$$h_1 = L_1sin(\theta)$$
$$h_2 = L_1sin(\theta_1) + L_1sin(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$$

And now I create the Langarian ODE matrix system:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial {\mathcal{L_i}}}{\partial\dot{x_i}}) - \frac{\partial {\mathcal{L_i}}}{\partial x_i} = 0 $$

By saying that:

$$x_1 = \theta_1 , x_2 = \dot{\theta_1}$$
$$x_3 = \theta_2 , x_4 = \dot{\theta_2}$$
$$x_5 = \theta_3 , x_6 = \dot{\theta_3}$$

Which means:

$$\dot{x_2} = \ddot{\theta_1}$$
$$\dot{x_4} = \ddot{\theta_2}$$
$$\dot{x_6} = \ddot{\theta_3}$$

**Question:**

Is this right? Can I create a dynamical ODE system by doing this:
$${\mathcal{L}}_1 = [\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + J_1\ddot{\theta_1}] - [m_1gh_1]$$
$${\mathcal{L}}_2 = [\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 + J_2\ddot{\theta_2}] - [m_2g(h_1 + h_2)]$$
$${\mathcal{L}}_3 = [J_3\ddot{\theta_3}] - [0]$$

Or is it more complicated than so?

**EDIT:**

It supposed to be like this:

$${\mathcal{L}}=  \sum_{i = 1}^n (KE_i - PE_i)$$

$${\mathcal{L}} = [\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2 + J_1\dot{\theta_1}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2 + J_2\dot{\theta_2}^2 + J_3\dot{\theta_3}^2] - [m_1gh_1 + m_2g(h_1 + h_2)]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only *one* Lagrangian for your system: it is obtained by *summing* all the contributions to the kinetic energy, and subtracting the sum of all the potential energies.

I will not check your calculations but it is unlikely that your various ${\cal L}_k$ are correct: the kinetic energy does not contain terms in $\ddot{\theta}_k$ but will be quadratic in the velocities, i.e would contain $\dot{\theta}_k^2$.  Moreover, it is not clear that the kinetic energy of each mass "separates out", i.e. the position of the second mass is dependent on the position of the first mass so the kinetic energy of the second mass will contain terms in $\theta_1$ and $x_1$.

This being said, once you have *the* correct Lagrangian yes you will obtain a system of coupled differential equations; it will likely be non-linear and so cannot be brought into matrix form in general, although by expanding about some specific points (usually the fixed points) you can linearize the equations of motion.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know that $$ {\mathcal{L}} = \sum_{i = 1}^n (KE_i - PE_i)$$ will give me only one long single equation. So insted of $\ddot{\theta}$  it will be $\dot{\theta}^2$ for intertia? So the mass $m_1$ affects mass $m_2$ and my equations are wrong? I need to make them both affect each other? I know that this are going to be a nonlinear equation. But I will linearize it with jacobian.

Comment: The rotational kinetic energy is usually $I\dot\theta^2$ but the rotational and translational degrees of freedom might not decouple (they don't in general), i.e you may have $\dot{x}\dot{\theta}$ terms.

Comment: Okej. Rotational kinetic energy. I was doing rotational kinetic force. Thanks. I have change my question down blow and added the right answer. I will check more about how and when rotational and translational degrees of freedom effects each other. Are that a specificic equation you pointing out? Is it the velocity equations?

Comment: Lagrangian mechanics is probably not the right method for me, due to the rotation? Is Hamiltonian mechanics better in this case?

Comment: Lagrangian is fine.  You will not get more out of a Hamiltonian.  The usual trick is to express the velocities in Cartesian first and then change to polar.  This way $v_i^2=(\dot x_i^2+\dot y_i^2)$ is clear and clean, and will get you there if you do the coordinate transformation right.

Comment: But I did $v^2 = \dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2$ ? I wonder if I should have one lagrangian for translation $x, y$ axis, and one langarian for rotation $z$ axis?

Comment: Your $x_2$ and $y_2$ are incorrect.  They depend on the location of the end of the first arm and so on $x_1$ and $y_1$ addition to $\theta_2$.   You have something like $x_1=L\cos\theta_1$ etc for the coordinate transformation.

Comment: Ok. So I need to think there is a particle in (0,0,0) which have rotation and translation and that particles got effected by the masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ and mass $m_2$ effects mass $m_1$. So the complete system will end up into a single equation?

Comment: There will be one and only one Lagrangian but it will result is one equation of motion per degree of freedom.

Comment: For example! The position of $x_2$ is $$x_2 = L_1 cos(\theta_1) + L_2 cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2) $$ And finding $\dot{x_2}$ is now very easy.

Comment: yeah something like this.

Comment: It will results multiple equations due to the $$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial {\mathcal{L_i}}}{\partial\dot{x_i}}) - \frac{\partial {\mathcal{L_i}}}{\partial x_i} = 0 $$ Right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this question is well answerd now. Time to go back to the drawing board...MS Paint ;)